# Need to send requestImage() some runtime generated URLs. Is this possible?

Tags: processing

I'm using a remote url for a *PImage*. It's a jpg from a cam. I'm grabbing it and sending it to a *image()* every sec. Switching to a new cam every 10 secs. Every hour or so, the script crashes due to a 502 error, since the image was not successfully downloaded.

I'm attempting to setup a script that looks at the image using *requestImage()*, does a quick error check, and skips draw of that image if it returns a 0 or -1. Which should be simple enough. But...

How can you send a constantly updating url to *requestImage()* if its parameters refuse to accept anything other than a static single filename in a string and it lives in *setup()* / pre-process?

Anyone run into this issue before? Or am I missing something?

Here is the code. Note: cams are not active at the moment, so there are placeholders in the array...;

Thanks for looking!

```java
PImage webImg;
PImage testImg;

int timer;

String[] camlist = {

"random_url_with_JPG_here",
"random_url_with_JPG_here",
"random_url_with_JPG_here"

};

//find length of array
int camListLength = int(random(camlist.length));

void setup() {

  testImg = requestImage(webImg, "jpg");

  noCursor();
  fullScreen();
  background(0);
}


void draw() {
  if (millis() - timer >= 10000) {
    camLoad();
    timer = millis();
  } else {
    displayWebImage();
  }
} 


void camLoad() {
  //find length of array
  camListLength = int(random(camlist.length));
}


   void displayWebImage() {

  // load random cam url into 'webImg'
  webImg = loadImage(camlist[camListLength], "jpg");

  // test load
  println(testImg.width);
  if (testImg.width == 0) {
    println("Not Loaded");
  } else if (testImg.width == -1) {
    println("random error");
  } else {
    // display 'webImage'
    image(webImg, 0, 0, 800, 480);
    // cache cleanup 
   g.removeCache(webImg);
    delay(1000);
    // frame count
    println(frameCount+" "+g.getCache(webImg));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is forcing you to only have `requestImage()` inside the `setup()` function. You can move it to the `draw()` function if you really want to.

Comment: Was sticking to the suggestions in the ref docs. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, for 95% of people, it's a bad idea to call `requestImage()` from the `draw()` function, because you don't want to load images 60 times per second. But you're trying to do something pretty specific, so it should be okay.

Comment: Thanks again. It just took adding a `delay()` after `requestImage()` to get it working. It's been running for about 12 hours without a hitch now, and has caught and avoided a 502 error 10-15 times.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. I think you can get rid of the `delay()` if you just use `loadImage()` instead. I've expanded my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that for 95% of people, it's a very bad idea to create images in the `draw()` function. Most programs should load all of the images at the beginning, in the `setup()` function.

But if you're loading images that you don't know ahead of time, then nothing is stopping you from creating images in the `draw()` function. You can absolutely call `requestImage()` from inside the `draw()` function.

But note that the `requestImage()` function runs in the background, so your code keeps executing while the image is requested. From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/requestImage_.html):

> This function loads images on a separate thread so that your sketch doesn't freeze while images load during setup(). While the image is loading, its width and height will be 0. If an error occurs while loading the image, its width and height will be set to -1.

This means that the image won't be loaded until a couple second later, so you can't use your image variable right away. You're fixing this using a call to `delay()`, but you're probably better off just using the `loadImage()` function instead. From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html):

> If the file is not available or an error occurs, null will be returned and an error message will be printed to the console. The error message does not halt the program, however the null value may cause a NullPointerException if your code does not check whether the value returned is null.
>
> ...
>
> Depending on the type of error, a PImage object may still be returned, but the width and height of the image will be set to -1. This happens if bad image data is returned or cannot be decoded properly. Sometimes this happens with image URLs that produce a 403 error or that redirect to a password prompt, because loadImage() will attempt to interpret the HTML as image data.

That function does not run in the background, so the code only continues after the image is fully loaded.